# Class variable has different value in different methods

Tags: java, android, scope

I have a class called `OurView`. I have 3 `Buttons` that call `moveImage()` and pass it two numbers depending on which `Button` it is.

`moveImage()` is supposed to change the value of `xCoord` and `yCoord`, which it seems to do. When `xCoord` and `yCoord` are printed from `moveImage()` they display the correct values.

But when printed from `delay()` or `doDraw()` they display the original value of 500.

Am I doing something incorrect that causes the variables to not be updated?

Here is the class OurView:

```
package com.thatoneprogrammerkid.gameminimum;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Bitmap testimg;
    private int xCoord = 500;
    private int yCoord = 500;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OurView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OurView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        testimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.testimg);
    }

    void moveImage(int xChange, int yChange) {
        this.xCoord = this.xCoord + xChange;
        this.yCoord = this.yCoord + yChange;
        System.out.println("Move Image");
        printCoords();
    }

    void printCoords() {
        System.out.println(xCoord);
        System.out.println(yCoord);
    }

    void delay() {
        System.out.println("Delay");
        printCoords();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
                System.out.println("Run");
                printCoords();

                if(canvas != null){
                    synchronized (getHolder()) {
                        doDraw(canvas, xCoord, yCoord);
                    }
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }

            }
        }, 33);
    }

    void doDraw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y) {
        xPos = this.xCoord + (testimg.getWidth()/2);
        yPos = this.yCoord + (testimg.getHeight()/2);
        System.out.println("Draw");
        printCoords();
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 55, 255, 255);
        canvas.drawBitmap(testimg, x, y, null);
        delay();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
       delay();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

}
```

Here is the class the handles the button presses:

```
package com.thatoneprogrammerkid.gameminimum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity {

    OurView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new OurView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_surface_view_example);
    }

    public void arrowPressed(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.arrowLeft:
                gameView.moveImage(-1,0);
                break;

            case R.id.arrowRight:
                gameView.moveImage(1,0);
                break;

            case R.id.arrowUp:
                gameView.moveImage(0,1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

To clarify, after pressing the button 10 times the printCoords() in moveImage() displays the following:

```
510
500
```

and the printCoords() in all the other locations displays the following:

```
500
500
```

Comment: delay() or doDraw() display the original value of 500 witch is correct, what do you expect ?

Comment: Are you calling delay() or doDraw() after the call to moveImage(). Also, can you check the parameters of moveImage to be sure that they are not 0, 0 ?

Comment: I am 100% sure that moveImage's parameters are not 0,0. Like I said in the post, if I change the xCoord and yCoord using moveImage and then print them from within moveImage, they reflect the right values (each press increments by one, so after 10 button presses the print function within moveImage prints "510 /n 500")

Answer (score 0):

If what I guess is right , the reference you use to call moveImage() and delay() are not the same . Maybe you did something like:

```
ourView = new OurView();
```

after calling moveImage.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be possible, seeing as I need an instance of the class to even call moveImage. If you're suggesting I have two instances, that also isn't the case. In my main class I have

`gameView = new OurView`

Comment: Can you post the methods where you call MoveImage() and delay()?

Comment: I just added the SurfaceViewExample class, which handles the button presses. delay() is first called from surfaceCreated(), and after that it is called from doDraw().

Comment: If you use SurfaceViewExample to call printCoords() and moveImage(), then you may have different instances of "SurfaceViewExample" . Or you hold different instances of the class which have SurfaceViewExample as an attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible to have two instances of SurfaceViewExample. As far as I know activities in android can't have duplicates. But even if it is possible, I don't know how I would have done that. My main activity simply has a button that calls this code:

`public void startSurfaceViewExample(View view) {
        Intent startSurfaceViewExample = new Intent(this, SurfaceViewExample.class);
        startActivity(startSurfaceViewExample);
    }`

Comment: set a breakpoint in startsurfaceViewExample() and you will know what's wrong

Comment: Could you give me more detail? Where should I put the breakpoint, and how would that help me? It's clear that it switches values between the different methods. Won't setting a breakpoint just re-affirm that?

Comment: I think you will find this method will be called more than once.

Comment: Set a method breakpoint or just put it anywhere in the method.

Comment: Maybe startSurfaceViewExample() is better

Comment: I put method breakpoints for the moveImage, delay, and doDraw methods. Like I said, this just reconfirmed what I already though. In moveImage xCoord and yCoord are equal to 510, and in delay and doDraw xCoord and yCoord are equal to 500.

Comment: Yeah , sure it is .You have two instances.

Comment: I have two instances of what? How can I check to see if I do have two instances of whatever you are talking about?